# Differed deep link android

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

I am developing an e-commerce android app I have a product page in my application. I want to implement share functionality in my app so if anyone share product the unique should be generated and specific should be opened only. I have  referred some sites like a branch but are not  find fully demo  so anyone that can give the reference that will be helpful

Comment: Use firebase , go through https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5tip9-S_4QIVjo6PCh3S5wWoEAAYASABEgKaivD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase dynamic link. It is very useful. If app is not installed, it will take the user to playstore link of your app. If installed then it will take the user to your desired activity based on your deeplink/dynamic link.. here is the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5tip9-S_4QIVjo6PCh3S5wWoEAAYASABEgKaivD_BwE.